# Did I correctly use the Voltage divider rule to derive the transfer function?

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-divider, transfer-function, current-divider

[image]

Question and diagram are on link and NOTICE Rs is assumed to be a short.

I believe the transfer function is going to be:

A(jw) = 1/(jw*C1*R3+1)

I arrived at this answer by using a simple voltage divider rule considering Vi to be the source voltage to the impedance of C1 and R3; the voltage across R1 is exactly the same as the input voltage Vi since it is given that Rs is a short.

Am I right by believing that the current across C1 and R3 is the same as the current across R1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Rs is a short, the resistor is in parallel to an ideal voltage and can be omitted.

The resulting circuit is a simple RC highpass but the equation is for a lowpass.
As noted in the captain's comment the correct expression should be:  1 / (1/(jw *R3*C1) + 1)
which can be rewritten as
$$
A(j\omega)=\frac{j\omega R_3 C_1}{1 + jw R_3 C_1}
$$

The current through C1 and R3 is the same, where else should the current go?

Comment: Will that same EXACT current go through R1 or Will a part of it go into the wire where Rs and Vs are?

Comment: Oh the equation was suppose to be 1 / ((R3/jw*C1) + 1).

Comment: I'll update my response.